# What do the colors mean on VS Code Maps?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-map

Created some code maps in Visual Studio 2013 to see if they help in any way. They're actually quite good. However, it has coloured various entities and I've no idea how it has decided what colour to use for what entity.

There are blue, dark purple and pink entities showing. At first glance, blue is interfaces and abstract classes, but not always, pink and purple I have no idea.

Second there are arrows connecting the entities which are also coloured and occassionally dotted. I've no idea what these are supposed to represent without actually looking at them. Again I need some sort of key.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the meaning of a block by looking at the symbol it contains. The colours can vary, you can change the colours also. What you should see is the symbols. Below is the list of symbols:

[image]

The links:

[image]

You can find this legend from the legend button on top of a codemap file. As you can see in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, I completely missed that button and I've been through clicking on everything.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `legend` button in the upper right corner of the code map window (or there should be). Clicking that gives this (for C++):

[image]